# Define "var" type out of a method scope

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method call like this:

```
public bool IsAlright(...)
{
    var myColumns = // some linq query.ToArray();

    var theirColumns = (from row in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"ConfigColumns.txt")
                        where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row)
                        select new { TheColumn = row.ToUpper() }).ToArray();

    bool isAlright = // join those two above and see if they have anything in commmon.FirstOrDefault

    return isAlright;
}
```

But I think reading the text file every time is a performance hit and I can do it just once.
So I am thinking of pulling it out but how? it is a "var" and I don't know how to pull out a "var" and define it out of the method scope like a cached object or something?

Comment: I think, it reads the file only once.

Comment: Why do you even need an anonymous type here? You can just project `row.ToUpper()` and make `theirColumns` a `string[]`.

Comment: `var` is not the variable's type - it just means that the compiler will infer what it is. Hover over it with the mouse in Visual Studio, that should tell what the type actually is.

Comment: Did you try changing var. With IQueriable?

Comment: @stackunderflow no didn't know about it

Comment: You can return dynamics, but don't.  Just define an class and select that instead.  Or better yet, take Lee's suggestion.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Obviously it's an anonymous object.

Comment: @stackunderflow Why would that help?

Comment: @emodendroket obviously? the code is not shown. In any case, it's still not a "var".

Comment: @Blorgbeard Why is it not obvious?  The code *is* shown.  And while the type isn't `var`, it's a type that can *only* be represented meaningfully through the use of `var`.  The fact that fields cannot be defined using `var` effectively means this type cannot be used.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The code is shown.  `select new { TheColumn = row.ToUpper() }).ToArray();`

Comment: I meant `IQueriable<T>`

Comment: @stackunderflow OK.  So why would that help?

Comment: So he can use it outside the method!! Also IQueriable I faster than IEnumerable,  Bec he is generating array

Comment: @stackunderflow So what's T?  That's the problem here.  You could use dynamics though (note:  bad idea).

Comment: @emodendroket thanx fir taking the time to clarify this. You are right: )

Comment: Technically, for _storing_ an array of an anonymous type in a field, you can use a field of type `object[]` (because the anonymous type derives from `object` and is a reference type and array types have this kind of covariance) but that is useless when you want to _read_ the properties of the array entries afterwards (which is why people mentioned `dynamic` of course). But clearly the recommended solution is to avoid anonymous types here and use an existing type, a `Tuple<,,...,>` or a user-defined named type (an ordinary class or struct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `var` keyword is not a type, it just means the compiler will infer the type based on the type of the right-hand side expression.

The type of your `var` is an array of an anonymous type.  You can't declare a field or method of an anonymous type (unless you use `object` or `dynamic`), so you need to declare a type that matches the interface of your anonymous object.

In your case, since you're only storing a string, I would recommend, just returning an array of `string` instead of using an object:

```
string[] theirColumns = (from row in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"ConfigColumns.txt")
                    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row)
                    select row.ToUpper()).ToArray();
```

You can now pull `theirColumns` out to a field in your class.

Comment: thanks and then the file read operation will only be done "once" ?

Comment: If you leave that code in the `IsAlright` method, it will still get called every time you call `IsAlright`.  You could check the field to see if its `null` and if so then read the file and store it in the field.  The next time through it will no longer be `null` so it won't try to read the file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use var outside of method scope. In your case you can either use string[] instead of custom anonymous object, or create a custom class. Then promote the variable to class field and use it in any other method that you need.

Comment: You mean an anonymous object.  var is irrelevant.

Comment: @emodendroket He uses the terms "`var` and "anonymous type" exactly right in this answer.  He says that you cannot use `var` outside of a method scope, which is quite right.  He suggests replacing the use of the anonymous object with a new custom class, which is the best solution to this problem.  The only terminology issue here is that "anonymous object" really should be "anonymous type" instead.

Comment: var is relevant. You cannot use it to define a class field, so you must use a known type, which in this case is either array of custom objects or an array of strings

Comment: You're confusing the issue a bit because var declarations usually refer to known types.

Comment: @emodendroket He's not confusing the issue at all.  Just because `var` *can* be used to refer to types that can be named explicitly is irrelevant.  *Here* it's not; *here* it's used to refer to an anonymous type.  This answer correctly states that `var` cannot be used to define the type of a field, and provides one valid means of accomplishing the OP's goals without using `var`, namely avoiding the use of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

First, Declare a class outside the method.

```
public class YourClassName
{
     public string TheColumn {set;get;}
}
```

I assume each row is just a string, change the type if it's not

change your theirColumns to

```
YourClassName[] theirColumns = (from row in   System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"ConfigColumns.txt")
                    where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row)
                    select new YourClassName { TheColumn = row.ToUpper() }).ToArray();
```

extract it outside the method.

Comment: Of course, you have to wonder what the value of a class with a single string field is.